# Show all occurrences of query while highlighting in solr 1.4

Tags: solr

I have a solr setup(1.4) having a text field with ebook data. The params while hitting solr are -

`"hl.fragsize":"0",
    "indent":"1",
    "hl.simple.pre":"{{{",
    "hl.fl":"body_eng",
    "hl.maxAnalyzedChars":"-1",
    "wt":"json",
    "hl":"true",
    "rows":"1",
    "fl":"ia,body_length,page_count",
    "q":"ia:talesofpunjabtol00stee AND PUNJAB",
    "q.op":"AND",
    "f.body_eng.hl.snippets":"428",
    "hl.simple.post":"}}}",
    "hl.usePhraseHighlighter":"true"}},`

However, the results show only 20 highlighted occurrences of word PUNJAB.
I tried `f.body_eng.hl.snippets":"428"` but this even isnt working.

body_eng is a big text field. The highlighting works only till some length. I have tried other words as well. In all the examples, highlighting works till around 54K letter counts.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after lot of asking around, Its working now.

The query params is correct. The schema was causing problems. Changes done were -

`<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />`

was replaced with

with `<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />`

Answer (score 2):

First of all: 1.4 is a very old version of Solr. I'm not sure if per field values were supported at that time (Highlighting itself was introduced with Solr 1.3). The default highlighter was changed in 3.1.

You should however be able to highlight all occurences in a field by supplying a large value for `hl.maxAnalyzedChars` (not sure if -1 will do what you want). Another option to try should be to have a large `hl.maxAnalyzedChars` value and a large `hl.fragsize` value (use the same value for both fields and not 0).

If you're still unable to get it to work, test it on a more recent version of Solr to see if it's an issue that has already been fixed.